# Cannot deploy workflows in Azure Standard Logic Apps with ASEv3 - ERROR: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='mylaname.scm.myasename.appserviceenvironment.net'

Tags: azure, azure-deployment, file-storage, azure-logic-app-standard, private-network

I cannot find a way to **deploy workflows into a Standard Logic App** when this Logic App is included in an App Service Plan included in an **Azure Service Environment (ASEv3).**

## STANDARD LOGIC APP WIHOUT ASE

When  I use a Standard Logic App without ASE, its content (Workflows, maps, schemas…) is stored in the **FileShare** of the Storage Account associated with the Standard Logic Apps (under **site\wwwroot**)
So updating or creating new workflows for a Logic App was pretty easy, just update the file workflow.json or create an extra folder with a new file workflow.json.

I could use CLI to upload a zip file with all workflows and artifacts.

`az logicapp deployment source config-zip --name $LogicApp --resource-group $RG --subscription $Subscription --src $artifactszip`

And that works fine.

## STANDARD LOGIC APP WITH ASE

But when I try the same with a Standard Logic App in an App Service Plan **associated with an ASE**, this does not work.

1. There's no FileStorage associated with the Standard Logic App
2. `az logicapp deployment source config-zip` fails with these errors:

> az : WARNING: Getting scm site credentials for zip deployment
> WARNING: Starting zip deployment. This operation can take a while to complete ...
> ERROR: The command failed with an unexpected error. Here is the traceback:
> ERROR: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='mylaname.scm.myasename.appserviceenvironment.net', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url:
> /api/zipdeploy?isAsync=true (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x068F51C0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno
> 11001] getaddrinfo failed'))

In both cases (without and with ASE), the target Logic App is a **stateless** Logic App.

## I TRIED ALSO WITH az deployment group create AND armclient

I tried also with `az deployment group create --resource-group $RG --template-file .\myarmfile.json`
That works fine for:

- App Service Environment - Microsoft.Web/hostingEnvironments
- App Service Plan - Microsoft.Web/serverfarms
- Standard Logic App - Microsoft.Web/sites

But not for

- Workflow in Standard Logic App - **Microsoft.Web/sites/workflow**

I used **ARMCLIENT** to get examples of arm files for Microsoft.Web/sites/workflow

`armclient.exe get https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{LAresourceGroup}/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/la-main-dev/workflows/wf-main-dev?api-version=2018-11-01`

That returns a nice arm file but I can't find a way to upload it to Azure.

Comment: I am amazed you got standard logic apps to work at all! Are you using a Visual Studio or Code project? I am getting so many errors with it I gave up and went to consumption.  Seems like (much like your issue) another Microsoft product which they expect customers to beta test for them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to **setup a DNS Private zone** as documented in Microsoft  Learn (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/environment/create-ilb-ase) :

To configure DNS in Azure DNS Private zones:

1. create an Azure DNS private zone named .appserviceenvironment.net
2. create an A record in that zone that points * to the ILB IP address
3. create an A record in that zone that points @ to the ILB IP address
4. create an A record in that zone that points *.scm to the ILB IP address

When this DNS zone is created and that I linked to it:

- the network of my ASE
- the network of my machine

then I can deploy successfully the workflows and other artifacts (parameters, Maps, Schemas) via:

- **Visual Studio Code - extension for Standard Logic App**

or

- PowerShell script

> **az webapp deployment source config-zip** --name $LA **--resource-group** $RG **--subscription** $Subscription **--src** $artifactszip